# Is it possible to have different details on every attachment? MS Access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, attachment

Good day, as the title says. Is it possible to have difference details on every attachment in MS Access?

I provided a screenshot here:

[See my screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loEk5.png)

As you can see, I will need to search one record. For example in the picture, "111"

In the record, "111". There are many attachments such as: mp3, pdf, ms word.

Is it possible to have difference attach_details for every attachment? I also want to show the attach_details whenever i change the current attachment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create separate table for attachments, add text field for attachment details and link this table with main table using Master-Child fields. Store one attachment per record. In this case you will be able to store as many attachents as you want, each attachent will have own searchable description.

Comment: Hello, Sergey S. Thank you for noticing my question. I will try your suggested solution. I will let you know if this works, thanks!